# returned function has undefined results array from parent function

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I'm trying to make a simple function to deep flatten an array using ES5. What I have below works, but seems to be suboptimal because the `res` results array is kept outside of the flatten function.

```js
    var arr = [1, 2, [3], [4, [5, [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]]]]
      , res = [];
    function flatten(item){
      if (Array.isArray(item)) {
       item.forEach(el => {
         return flatten(el, res);
       });
      }else {
        res.push(item);
      }
    }
    
    flatten(arr);
    console.log(res); //[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```

Something like with an IIFE seems like it is close:

```
function flatten(item){
  var res = [];
  return (function(ress){
    if (Array.isArray(item)) {
     item.forEach(el => {
       return flatten(el);
     });
    }else {
      res.push(item);
    }
  })(res);
}
```

But I haven't got it quite right because `res` is undefined here.  Ideally I'd like to have the final line of the function return `res` so that the function could be used like `var f = flatten(arr)`.

#### NB

*This question isn't specifically about how to deep flatten an array, as there are lots of answers about that. What I'me really interested in is how I can keep the results variable inside the parent function in this instance
*

Comment: @Barmar Updated

Comment: The problem is you're setting `res` to `[]` each time you make the recursive call.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, I did try something at one point that was like `res = res || [];` but still got a reference error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nest the recursive function inside the main function. Then you can can have the `res` variable inside the main function.

```js
var arr = [1, 2, [3],
  [4, [5, [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]]]
];

function flatten(item) {
  var res = [];

  function flatten_rec(item) {
    if (Array.isArray(item)) {
      item.forEach(el => {
        flatten_rec(el);
      });
    } else {
      res.push(item);
    }
  }
  
  flatten_rec(item);
  return res;
}

var res = flatten(arr);
console.log(res); //[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different approach using `Array.prototype.reduce`.

```js
var arr = [1, 2, [3], [4, [5, [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]]]];

var res = arr.reduce( function flatten (a, b) {
  if (Array.isArray(a) && Array.isArray(b)) {
    return b.reduce(flatten, a)
  } else {
    return a.concat(b)
  }
}, [])

console.log(res)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  top: 0;
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An iterative approach to this is much better than recursion, in my opinion.

```
// Deep copy all arguments into a new, single-level array.
const flatten = (...queue) => {
    const result = [];

    while (queue.length > 0) {
        const item = queue.shift();

        if (Array.isArray(item)) {
            let i = item.length;
            // If the array is non-empty, add its children to the beginning
            // of the queue to keep their order intact.
            while (i--) {
                queue.unshift(item[i]);
            }
        }
        else {
            result.push(item);
        }
    }

    return result;
};
```